# A single url for many urls with common ending

Tags: django

I want to submit a form from any page. For that I have kept the form in base.html. But when a user submits the form, it redirects to a page with different url from different page. For an example, when user is on localhost:8000/example1/page1/ and click submit button it takes to the url localhost:8000/example1/page1/**submit**.. when user is on localhost:8000/example2/page2/something/else/ and click submit button it takes to the localhost:8000/example2/page2/something/else/**submit**.. One solution that I can think of is to have all these urls in my urls.py file to ensure smooth routing. But I feel that's not the right way to do. Second solution I think of is to put a button to redirect to the form on the base html so that it appears on all page and when a user has to fill the form he can click it and go. But I want the form to appear on every page on the sidebar. Any suggestion would be highly helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You can override onsubmit event for setting `action` the form attribute from `document.location.pathname` (without preventDefault). I think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have one same url there to submit form to, i.e. `/myform/submit` (not relative to current page `submit` path). That way this form on any page will submit to same url.

To distinguish in form / view between submits from different pages:

- forms on each page may have different data or some attribute set to page name
- `request.META.HTTP_REFERER` may contain origin page url - can be used to redirect back to origin page after submit or other checks (but requires validation that it contains correct / allowed url).

Comment: It took me a while to understand it.. but finally helped to resolve my issue.. Thanks for your time. I added the url in my submit button's "formaction" attribute. Earlier I was trying to add the action in my form's action attribute. I removed the action attribute of the form tag. Because of that it was redirecting me to new page if I start from a new page.